# How to "map" between 3 values?

Tags: perl, data-structures

I have lots of data like this

```
type1, type2, type3
aax, ert, ddd
asx, eer, kkk
xkk, fff, lll
xxj, vtt, lle
...
```

and I would really like to be able to "map" between them, so I can go from

```
type1 -> type2
type1 -> type3
type2 -> type1
type3 -> type1
```

Example:

```
type1_to_type2(aax) should return ert
type1_to_type3(asx) should return kkk
type2_to_type3(fff) should return lll
type3_to_type1(lle) should return xxj
```

What data structure should be used for the data?

And how would such functions look like?

**Update**: All data is unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version that actually implements the 'type1_to_type2' etc... functions.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $data;
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  push @$data, [ split ];
}

sub typeX_to_typeY {
  my ($x, $y, $str) = @_;

  foreach (@$data) {
    if ($_->[$x - 1] eq $str) {
      return $_->[$y - 1];
    }
  }

  return;
}

sub type1_to_type2 { typeX_to_typeY(1, 2, @_) }
sub type1_to_type3 { typeX_to_typeY(1, 3, @_) }
sub type2_to_type1 { typeX_to_typeY(2, 1, @_) }
sub type2_to_type3 { typeX_to_typeY(2, 3, @_) }
sub type3_to_type1 { typeX_to_typeY(3, 1, @_) }
sub type3_to_type2 { typeX_to_typeY(3, 2, @_) }

# tests
use Test::More tests => 4;

is(type1_to_type2('aax'), 'ert');
is(type1_to_type3('asx'), 'kkk');
is(type2_to_type3('fff'), 'lll');
is(type3_to_type1('lle'), 'xxj');

__DATA__
aax ert ddd
asx eer kkk
xkk fff lll
xxj vtt lle
```

Answer (score 3):

If all the strings are unique, you can use them as keys in a hash:

```
my %data = (
    aax => ["aax", "ert", "ddd"],
    ert => ["aax", "ert", "ddd"],
    ddd => ["aax", "ert", "ddd"],
    asx => ["asx", "eer", "kkk"],
    ...
);

sub get_value {
    my ($s, $type) = @_;
    return $data{$s}[$type-1];
}

print get_value("aax", 2); # "ert"
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use a database for this sort of thing. Here's an illustration:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=demo_db","","");

# Initialize an SQLite DB with some content.
my @init_db = (
    'CREATE TABLE demo (ty1 VARCHAR(5), ty2 VARCHAR(5), ty3 VARCHAR(5));',
    'INSERT INTO demo (ty1, ty2, ty3) values ("aax", "ert", "ddd");',
    'INSERT INTO demo (ty1, ty2, ty3) values ("asx", "eer", "kkk");',
    'INSERT INTO demo (ty1, ty2, ty3) values ("xkk", "fff", "lll");',
    'INSERT INTO demo (ty1, ty2, ty3) values ("xxj", "vtt", "lle");',
);

for my $s (@init_db){
    $dbh->do($s) or die $!;
}

# Query the data by any field we like.
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM demo');
$sth->execute();
my $result = $sth->fetchall_hashref('ty1');
```

The result is a reference to a hash of hashes, keyed by the value of `ty1` and then by the field names in our table. For example:

```
$result->{xkk} = {
  'ty2' => 'fff',
  'ty3' => 'lll',
  'ty1' => 'xkk'
};
```

If you're interested in just one particular value of a given field, you can use a more specific query. With this approach it's very easy to write utility methods -- for example, take a field name and a value of interest, and return the results in whatever format is most handy.

Answer (score 2):

Use one array, containing:

```
(
  ['aax', 'ert', 'ddd'],
  ['asx', 'eer', 'kkk'],
  ...,
)
```

and an array of three hashrefs, the first hashref containing:

```
{
  aax => $array[0],
  asx => $array[1],
  ...,
}
```

the second hashref containing:

```
{
  ert => $array[0],
  eer => $array[1],
  ...,
}
```

etc (with all three of the hashes pointing into entries in the same original array). Then to find the "column three" value corresponding to "column 1 = 'asx'", the lookup is just `$table[0]{asx}[2]`, which will give "kkk".

Comment: This solution also works fine, even if the data is only positionally unique (per column). Of course, the fact that no function calls are required here may recommend it in terms of speed, although I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

If all the strings are globally unique then the 'eugene' solution will work fine.

If the strings are not globally unique then they will at least need to be positionally unique in order for your question to make sense (unless of course multiple answers are permissible); i.e. the values should be unique by column.

If this is the case then you can use the eugene-solution but append the column-number to the hash key, as in so:

```
my %data = (
    aax1 => ["aax", "ert", "ddd"],
    ert2 => ["aax", "ert", "ddd"],
    ddd3 => ["aax", "ert", "ddd"],
    asx1 => ["asx", "eer", "kkk"],
    ...
);

sub get_value {
    my ($string, $from_type, $to_type) = @_;
    return $data{$string . $from_type }[ $to_type - 1 ];
}

print get_value("aax", 1, 2); # "ert"
```

Comment: Be careful concatenating hash keys.  You are almost always better off to add another layer to your data structure rather than do this.  Speed is only one concern.  The other big issue is with correctness.  Expand our data set a bit and consider: is 'foo11' `foo1' in column one or 'foo' in column 11?  By keeping separate keys separate, you avoid the hassle of parsing and building keys, and you also remove the burden of picking a safe, guaranteed unambiguous key encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Let's begin by imagining the world we'd like to exist.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Convert q(
  type1, type2, type3
  aax,   ert,   ddd
  asx,   eer,   kkk
  xkk,   fff,   lll
  xxj,   vtt,   lle
);
```

With that bit of front matter, we ought to be able to call a few handy functions:

```
use Test::More;

diag type1_to_type2("aax");
diag type1_to_type3("asx");
diag type2_to_type3("fff");
diag type3_to_type1("lle");
```

The results should correspond to what's in the table.

```
my @tests = (
  [ qw/ type1_to_type2 aax ert / ],
  [ qw/ type1_to_type3 asx kkk / ],
  [ qw/ type2_to_type3 fff lll / ],
  [ qw/ type3_to_type1 lle xxj / ],
  [ qw/ type2_to_type1 ert aax / ],
);

my %sub_ok;
for (@tests) {
  my($name,$from,$expect) = @$_;

  my $sub;
  { no strict 'refs';
    unless ($sub_ok{$name}++) {
      ok defined &$name, "$name defined"
        or next;
    }
    $sub = \&$name;
  }

  is $sub->($from), $expect, "$name($from)";
}

done_testing;
```

To make it happen, the Convert module needs to take a specification and generate the appropriate subs.

The code in `Convert.pm` begins with familiar boilerplate.

```
package Convert;

use strict;
use warnings;
```

[According to the perlfunc documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html), `use Module LIST` is equivalent to

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
```

so Convert's `import` needs to take the table as one of its arguments. (The first, which we ignore, is the string `"Convert"` because `import` is called as a class method.)

```
sub import {
  my(undef,$spec) = @_;

  my %map;
  my @names;
  _populate(\%map, \@names, $spec);

  my $pkg = caller;
  foreach my $n1 (@names) {
    foreach my $n2 (@names) {
      next if $n1 eq $n2;

      my $sub = sub {
        my($preimage) = @_;
        return unless exists $map{$n1}{$n2}{$preimage};
        $map{$n1}{$n2}{$preimage};
      };

      my $name = $pkg . "::" . $n1 . "_to_" . $n2;
      { no strict 'refs'; *$name = $sub; }
    }
  }
}
```

With `_populate`, explained below, we construct a hash whose keys are

1. *from-name*
2. *to-name*
3. *pre-image*

For example, the first data row in the specification (aax, ert, ddd) corresponds to six (= <sub>3</sub>P<sub>2</sub>) entries:

1. `$map{type1}{type2}{aax} = "ert"`
2. `$map{type1}{type3}{aax} = "ddd"`
3. `$map{type2}{type1}{ert} = "aax"`
4. `$map{type2}{type3}{ert} = "ddd"`
5. `$map{type3}{type1}{ddd} = "aax"`
6. `$map{type3}{type2}{ddd} = "ert"`

Having the hash, we then install subs (*e.g.*, `type1_to_type2`) in the caller's namespace where each looks up its argument in the appropriate slot and returns the mapped [image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29) if it exists.

In `_populate`, we grab the column names from the first non-empty row. For the remaining data rows, every pair of values goes into the map.

```
sub _populate {
  my($map,$names,$spec) = @_;

  my $line;
  for (split /\s*\n\s*/, $spec) {
    ++$line;
    my @fields = split /\s*,\s*/;
    next unless @fields;

    if (@$names) {
      my %f;
      @f{@$names} = @fields;
      unless (@fields == @$names) {
        warn "$0: line $line: number of fields and columns do not match!\n";
        next;
      }

      foreach my $n1 (@$names) {
        foreach my $n2 (@$names) {
          next if $n1 eq $n2;
          my($f1,$f2) = @f{$n1,$n2};

          my $slot = \$map->{$n1}{$n2}{$f1};
          warn "$0: line $line: discarding $$slot ($n1 -> $n2)\n"
            if defined $$slot;

          $$slot = $f2;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      @$names = @fields;
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to have the module return a true value at the end.

```
1;
```

Finally, the output!

```
# ert
# kkk
# lll
# xxj
ok 1 - type1_to_type2 defined
ok 2 - type1_to_type2(aax)
ok 3 - type1_to_type3 defined
ok 4 - type1_to_type3(asx)
ok 5 - type2_to_type3 defined
ok 6 - type2_to_type3(fff)
ok 7 - type3_to_type1 defined
ok 8 - type3_to_type1(lle)
ok 9 - type2_to_type1 defined
ok 10 - type2_to_type1(ert)
1..10
```